# How to get the product of numbers gotten from combinations of datasets

Tags: javascript, combinations

I have a combinatoric script that's working fine, actually got most of it from the IBM dev website. But I want to be able to not just show the possible combinations, but also extract the numbers on each combination and get the product of the entire numbers. The project am working on mixes numbers (quantity) with strings (codename). So after combining them, i extract the number from each string and get the product of all the numbers in each combination. As shown;

[A2,B4,C5] = 2*4*5 = 40

Here is my javascript code that gets the combination, not to worry, I ran it with a test array of numbers 1-6, without the characters as shown above.

```
var Util = function() {
};

Util.getCombinations = function(array, size, start, initialStuff, output) {
if (initialStuff.length >= size) {
    output.push(initialStuff);
} else {
    var i;

    for (i = start; i < array.length; ++i) {    
    Util.getCombinations(array, size, i + 1, initialStuff.concat(array[i]), output);
    }
}
}

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations = function(array, size, output) {
Util.getCombinations(array, size, 0, [], output);
}

// Create an array that holds numbers from 1 ... 6.
var array = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
array[i - 1] = i;
}

var output = [];
var resultArray = [];

Util.getAllPossibleCombinations(array, 4, output);


for(var j=0; j<output.length; j++) {

    resultArray += output[j] + "=" + "<br />";
 }

 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = resultArray;

 });
```

I tried running this code inside the last for loop to get my multiplication, but it's just not executing, i must be doing something wrong. Here is the code;

```
        var inputval = output[j].replace(/[^,.0-9]/g, '');
        inputval = inputval.slice(0, -1);
        var hoArray = inputval.split(',');
         var cunt= hoArray.length;
         var ans=1;

         for(var m=0; m<cunt; m++)
         {
            ans *= hoArray[m];
        }
```

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

walk the array then walk the string, then cast and see if it is an integer then tally and sum the product.

```js
let array = ['A20', 'B11', 'C5'];

function getProduct(ar) {
    let product = 1;
    for (let x of ar) {
        let semiProduct = [];
        for (let i of x) {
            if (Number.isInteger(+i)) {
                semiProduct.push(i);
            }
        }
     product *= semiProduct.join('');
    }
    return product;
}
console.log(getProduct(array))
```

You could also use a regular expression.

```js
let array = ['A20', 'B11', 'C5'];

function getProduct(ar) {
    let product = 1;
    for (let x of ar) { 
        product *= x.match(/\d+/)[0];
    }
    return product;
}

console.log(getProduct(array))
```

If you want a way to generate permutations, you can utilize a generator to make things more concise.

```js
let array = ['A20', 'B11', 'C5'];

function* permu(arr, l = arr.length) {
  if (l <= 0) yield arr.slice();
  else
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      yield* permu(arr, l - 1);
      const j = l % 2 ? 0 : i;
      [arr[l - 1], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[l - 1]];
    }
}
console.log(
  Array.from(permu(array))
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, I'll see how I can get that into my program. It should work just perfectly. Though I tried placing it in the for loop that contain the resultArray and it wasn't responding fine, I'll get it working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @optimalresource I also added a more concise way for you to generate permutation.

Comment: Hello @Rick, I finally got it to work exactly how I want it to. Check the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/optimalresource/4k18hnow/9/

Answer (score 1):

When I run that code in the console it throws an error because output[j] is an array `[1,2,3,4]` and it looks like you're expecting it to be a string. Arrays do not have a replace method in JS.

You should run this:

```
var count= hoArray.length; 
var ans=1;   
for(var m=0; m<count; m++)
    {
        ans *= hoArray[m];
    }
```

And put `output[j]` instead of hoArray. And don't do any of this:

```
    var inputval = output[j].replace(/[^,.0-9]/g, '');
    inputval = inputval.slice(0, -1);
    var hoArray = inputval.split(',');
```

Comment: Ok, how do you think am gonna handle it, I tried it and it's throwing error repeatedly, that's why I came to post the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's great, but the real project as I said above will not be having just numbers in the array, it will have strings concatenated with numbers and I have to first of all separate them into another array which will contain just numbers for me to deal on with the multiplication operator. Please see if you can help me get that one exactly.

Comment: Your update is great, it's working, but I need a solution for the [A2,B4,C5] array instead of the [1,2,3,4,5,6] array. Thanks